# Why Gmap and App Map do not work on Emulator?

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, android-emulator

I use **Eclipse** and **Android SDK** to develop apps for android,recently i wrote a program to show a **map** on it, it works fine on real device but it don't show any map on emulator.

I check the emulator internet connection and it works and i checked the browser on emulator and it works and i checked the Google map app on the emulator and it show me an black page.

I think about a graphical library or something would be missing, is it possible ? what can i do to correct it?

PS:

1-I use **Google APIs 4.2.2 image**.

2-I know there are many emulator but they don't works with **DDMS** on Eclipse.for example DDMS can't send GPS location or SMS to theme or call theme.and i want some **log system** like LogCat.

Comment: because Emulator doesn't have `googleplay services` installed which is required for MAP.

Comment: you need google api 4.2.2 or higher to test map on emulator

Comment: brother you have to create the third party emulator called genymotion behaving like real devices because android emulator doesn`t support the google play services......

Comment: maps require google play services so you need to have google play api platfrom 4.2.2 or higher and you can test map app on emulator

Comment: I have installed google-play services with sdk maneger and i use Google APIs 4.2.2 image.

Comment: @Shombol-shagol then it will work read http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Comment: @MohammadKhatri Dose it meat the feature i asked in question?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use **genny motion** . Its works like real device.

http://www.genymotion.com/

[android genymotion vs emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18683656/android-genymotion-vs-emulator)

Answer (score 0):

use the following steps to make avd for s4 or any type:withe help of genymotion third party pulgin:

download first genymotion https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/launchpad/download/

cmd for install genymotion http://schier.co/post/install-genymotion-2.0-in-ubuntu

then: The installation of the plugin can be done by launching Eclipse and going to "Help / Install New Software" menu, then just add a new Update Site with the following URL: http://plugins.genymotion.com/eclipse.

installing the google play service from the following : http://blog.zeezonline.com/2013/11/install-google-play-on-genymotion-2-0/

Answer (score 0):

Genny Motion is the best solution by far and had almost all features a developer needs.

But the reason that i cant see the map is the time i should wait and https protocol which is  don't work properly in our country because of it's encryption ,it seems it took a while to appear a map, i left the program to eat dinner , when i came back it appears !!! but Google map App still don't work , maybe it needs time too.

Answer (score 0):

Emulator does not having gps hardware to run google map, that the reason it's showing blank, To run Map we need both a internet and gps as well.