# Android Emulator for MAC

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation

I am creating an app in corona, but since I am using push notifications, I cant use the corona simulator
What are some good Android Emulators to run apk files on mac? I tried Bluestack and andy, they don't allow me to run my custom apk files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try **Genymotion Emulator**. It is a fast third-party emulator that can be used instead of the `default Android emulator`. It is definitely `faster` than virtual devices from the **AVD Manager**. This is because Genymotion uses the `x86 architecture` to run, which is great for performance.

Genymotion has a `sidebar` that loads on the right side of a virtual device and the sidebar allows the ability to test the `GPS`, use a `camera`, change the virtual device’s `battery stats`, `capture videos` and much more.

You can do more with Genymotion Emulator. Just give it a try...
See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18684017/4608334) also to know more about Genymotion's performance.
Download Genymotion Emulator from [here](https://www.genymotion.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Why not the official Android emulators?

https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html

[Android Debug Bridge](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html) is very easy to use. You can run [`adb install`](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html#move) to install your own apks to the emulator.

You can also send push notifications to the emulator.

Comment: Can we install any application from th playstore on the official android emulator.