# Android Studio Emulator issues

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am new to android studio, and I do not have an android phone, so the first thing I actually tried to do is to try out the emulator before I get any further into android studio, but I am facing alot of problems.

When I press on the RUN button, I do find a "Nexus 5X API 27 X86" by default, when I run it, well here comes the problems. Sometimes it runs and opens properly, but without being able to find my app on the device, sometimes the app opens automatically. The device is always so slow, most of the times when I try to open an app, I get a msg "APP(google most of the time) has stopped working" or "Android is starting.." out of nowhere, and that same msg sometimes pops out automatically when I first run the emulator. Sometimes I get "Application Installation Failed" error, found some solutions saying to trun off instant run, I turned it off and I still get the error sometimes.

Generally, it is just impossible to start coding with such device, I had an android phone before and it was much easier.

As far as I know, my laptop should easily support both the android studio and the emulator.

One more thing, whenever I try to set up a new device on kitkat or something, the device doesnt come alive, just a stuck black screen with a logo in the middle.

My laptop:

Intel Core i7-5500U 2.4GHz

4gb RAM + 8gb RAM

Nvidia GeForce 920m - 2gb

64bit

And yeah, HAXM is installed.

Android Studio 3.0.1

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: use genymotion instead. It is very light compared to android studio

Answer (score 0):

You can try genymotion if you feel android emulator is slow. https://www.genymotion.com/

you can find the difference between the android emulator and genymotion.

[android genymotion vs emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18683656/android-genymotion-vs-emulator)

Comment: I can try it, but I am not saying that the android emulator is slow, as I have read it is actually faster than genymotion. But there is just something wrong I am doing, or missing something. It is not working how it is supposed to do, thats my point.

Answer (score 0):

Emulator's now is much faster and better then genymotion,just create your own device going to avd manager and then try to run it,one more thing , did you turn on intel virtualization in bios ?

Comment: yeah well, i am using the emulator. No, how to do that? Can you give me a link or something?

Comment: you have a lot of links about that but here's one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Cv2Hj2PlQE ,tell me if that doesn't help you

Comment: also check if you have latest google play services installed and if you have message that app stopped working then you should provide logcat error

Comment: The intel virtualization appeared to be enabled already, according to the Task Manager > Performance. Google Play Services wasnt installed and I just installed it now. Anything else I can do to make the emulator work better? It there a proper way to setup a new device or the current default device /should/ work properly?

Comment: yes that was my bad didn't see that u already installed haxm if virtualization was disabled u would have message to install,all I can help now is that when you create new device it should be with x86 system image with google apis not armeabi